# Mysterious 'File does not exist' error (in code unrelated to any kind of file IO) in global.asax

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010, jquery-ui, filenotfoundexception

I'm getting a 'File does not exist' error. In my ASP.NET app. This is a strange one, though.

Firstly, there is no file IO code anywhere around - I'm not doing anything with any files when it occurs.

Also, it's happening on the very last closing curly brace of the Application_Error() method in global.asax (that's the one you put code in to handle unhandled exceptions). That's right: it doesn't occur on a throw statement, or any line of meaningful code, but *right on the last curly brace*.

The TargetSite is:

> {System.IO.FileInfo
>   GetFileInfo(System.String,
>   System.String,
>   System.Web.HttpResponse)}

Which looks to me like something internal to ASP.NET (there is no GetFileInfo() method in my solution).

The StackTrace is only:

> at
>   ASP.global_asax.Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Subversion\ConfApp\Website\Global.asax:line 36    at
>   System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RaiseOnError()

From which I can derive no clues.

Other details:

- I'm in the middle of trying to resolve conflicts between jQuery 1.4 (and jquery UI) and MS ASP.NET AJAX 4 in this app at the moment
- It started after I upgraded the app from .net 2.0 to .net 4 and visual studio 2010.

Any idea how I might start looking into this?

**Update:**
Shortly after posting this, I removed and re-added jquery UI (including .js, .css and the images). So far, it looks like this has fixed it. Not sure how a client-side JS library might cause an error in Global.asax. Will add this as the answer, though, if error doesn't show up again soon...

Comment: one thing to consider.. If you are routing all files through the asp.NET handler (like with mvc) a missing JS file may cause such an exception

Comment: I'm not using MVC, and I'm not sure what it means to route all files through the asp.net handler (that's in IIS right - .aspx files etc go through it, but normally images and css and whatever go through something else?). It's a complex page with a bunch of homespun ajax, asp.net ajax, and jQuery on it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A day later, and the problem appears to be gone.

**I removed and re-added jquery UI** (including .js, .css and the images). So far, it looks like this has fixed it. Very strange.

Answer (score 4):

Within the ApplicationError method, check Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath.  CurrentExecutionFilePath should indicate which file was requested.

Checking this property helped me determine that Chrome automatically requests "/favicon.ico." If there is no favicon, you'll get a "File does not exist," even thought the page loads just fine. BTW, IE and FF do not behave this way.

Comment: you just saved me HOURS of searching.  Evil Chrome!!  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks.  Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath was a lifesaver.

Answer (score 1):

Using Perry's suggestion of examining `Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath` in `Application_Error`, I found that my ASP.Net app couldn't find the jQuery files in folders prefixed with `"~/"` in the `<script>` tag.

I was doing this in my MasterPage markup:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript">
```

when I should have been doing this:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript">
```